# hacer un formulario dinámico en access

Tags: ms-access

estoy intentado realizar un subformulario dinámico que se haga la query dependiendo lo que tenga en los diferentes inputs del formulario, sin embargo, al realizar la carga me aparece este error.

```
Se ha producido error "3000" en tiempo de ejecución
error reservado (-3201); no hay ningún mensaje de error
```

el código que tengo es el siguiente

```
Dim consulta As String
        If Not IsNull(Me.txtNotas Or Me.txtFechaFin Or Me.txtFechaInicio Or Me.cboTrabajador) Then
            consulta = "select * from pedido_compra where notas like '" & Me.txtNotas.Value & "' or trabajador = " & Me.cboTrabajador.Value & " or fec_solicitud between #" & Me.txtFechaInicio.Value & "# and #" & Me.txtFechaFin.Value & "#;"

            Me.pedido_compra.Form.RecordSource = "select * from pedido_compra where notas like '" & Me.txtNotas.Value & "' or trabajador = " & Me.cboTrabajador.Value & " or fec_solicitud between #" & Me.txtFechaInicio.Value & "# and #" & Me.txtFechaFin.Value & "#;"
        End If
```

Comment: Muchísimas veces en VBA es mejor hacer una consulta SQL pasando las fechas a números que usando "#" que sí funciona en SQL pero en VBA no lo coge. Conviértelo a dobles con `CDbl` y olvídate de las `#`. Y otra cosa, ¿qué tipo de control es `pedido_compra`? ¿Es el formulario activo? ¿Por qué no usar solo `Me.RecordSource` o `Me.Form.RecordSource`?

Comment: pedid_compra es el subformulario que lleva la consulta, ya que uso dos formularios, el principal en el que el usuario ingresa los valores a buscar y el secundario donde se muestra, funciona como una tabla en otro lenguaje de programación

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes varios errores en el código que muestras.

La primera línea no es coherente por dos motivos: el primero es que preguntas si es nulo un control (no su valor), lo cual no es correcto. En segundo lugar, realizas una secuencia de comprobaciones errónea poniendo dentro de la función `IsNull` una serie de controles.

Las dos primeras líneas de tu código deberían ser

```
Dim consulta As String
If Not IsNull(Me.txtNotas.Value) And not IsNull(Me.txtFechaFin.Value) And not IsNull(Me.txtFechaInicio.Value) and not IsNull(Me.cboTrabajador.Value) Then
```

Probablemente el error se soluciona con la corrección anterior, pero cuando realizas la consulta, está mal estructurada siguiendo la lógica `and/or` y debería quedar así

```
consulta = "select * from pedido_compra where notas like '" & Me.txtNotas.Value & "' or trabajador = " & Me.cboTrabajador.Value & " or (fec_solicitud between #" & Me.txtFechaInicio.Value & "# and #" & Me.txtFechaFin.Value & "#);"
```

Atención especial a los paréntesis. Desconozco el resultado esperado y puede que estos paréntesis necesiten algún retoque.

Comment: hice el cambio que propusiste, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema, el error lo arroja en la sección del código donde intento mandar la consulta al formulario. Por otra parte lo que está en el paréntesis es para que los resultados los arroje entre dos fechas, la consulta está bien, ya la probé y arroja los resultados esperados